# Gridview not working on windows server 2008 but working on windows 7 IIS

Tags: asp.net, gridview, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am trying to display some data in a gridview using the DataBind function. I am fetching the data from a MySql database into a DataSet. I am setting the DataSource of the gridview to the DataSet and then using the DataBind function.

viewFeedbacksGridView is the id of the gridview and dataSet_result is the corresponding DataSet.

```
viewFeedbacksGridView.DataSource = dataSet_result;
viewFeedbacksGridView.DataBind();
```

The code is displaying the data correctly on my machine running Windows 7 (IIS7). But, it does not display anything on the server running Windows Server 2008 Enterprise.

Please Help!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if there is any data in the datasource?

Comment: Yes, I have checked. There is data in the source. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: @user1065432 are you sure that there is data in datasource when application is running on server? how did you check that, you can debug the code on server and see the datasource data??